# Strange JSON keys

Tags: json, ajax

```
{
  "Meta Data": {
    "1: Symbol": "MSFT",
    "2: Indicator": "Triple Exponential Moving Average (TEMA)",
    "3: Last Refreshed": "2017-06-26 16:00:00",
    "4: Interval": "15min",
    "5: Time Period": 10,
    "6: Series Type": "close",
    "7: Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
}
}
```

Let me first start off by saying that I just started learning JSON and AJAX, so this may sound like a stupid question. Recentely though, I found this JSON output text. But there a couple of problems I have with it. First of all, some keys have two words in them, without a _ . How can you then use them in javascript? I mean you cannot have a method with a space in it, right? And my second problem is related to the first problem, since there are also some keys that even start out like this 1: or 2: . What's up with that? So if anyone can show me how I can for example reach the "5: time period" key in javascript, that would be a huge help.

Answer (score 3):

The keys in this case are just strings, so you would access them using strings. Assuming you've loaded this JSON into a `val` variable, you could use

```
val["Meta Data"]["1: Symbol"]
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be easy, just couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: And that would mean that I could also use val[0][0], correct?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't need a `_` is because anything between quotes in JSON is a string, and all the characters within are part of that same string object.

You can access JSON properties in JavaScript either using bracket notation (`[]`) or object notation (`object.property`). In this case, since your property is a string with a space, you'd have to use bracket notation.

So, assuming you have this object stored as a variable (say `obj` for example purposes), you could get `5: Time Period` by doing `obj["5: Time Period"]`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It really does help but is it also possible to do this obj[4]?

Comment: No, because you have something like `"4: Interval"` all within the same string. If you wanted the `4` to be a property on its own, you'd have to do something like `{ 4: { "Interval": ...`